# Joda Time Interval Not returning what I expect

Tags: java

I have the following program

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import org.joda.time.*;


public class ScopeControl {

    public static Interval getInterval() {

        DateTime currDate = new DateTime(2008, 4, 4, 15, 30, 0, 0);
        DateTime epochDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0);
        Interval interval = new Interval(epochDate, currDate);
        return interval;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double daysBtween  = getInterval().toDurationMillis()/1000/60/60/24;

             StdOut.println(daysBtween);
    }
}
```

I'm getting the output:
3016.0

but what I'm looking for is:
3016.1458333333

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Fix the integer division to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

toDurationMillis returns a long, and every division was declared as an int.  Java will thus convert the ints to longs and perform the divisions returning a long.  Converting the result to a double at the end.  To tell Java to perform the expression using doubles, declare any of the components of the expression as a double.  For example:

```
double daysBtween  = getInterval().toDurationMillis()/1000d/60d/60d/24d;
```

Comment: `1000d` or `1000.0` only needed on the first term

Comment: Thanks, that did it...I'm new to Java so did not know I needed to have the division that way.